# Using StringMap in OCamllex

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex

I'm trying to write a OCamllex parser that constructs a string map of words from a list. However, I receive an "Unbounded module" error when I attempt to open the StringMap module in the header:

```
{
  open StringMap
  type token = EOF | Word of string
}
(* other code *)
```

The same error occurs when I don't explicitly open the module, and when I try to create a map within the trailer:

```
module StringMap = Map.Make (String)
```

All the OCaml tutorials suggest I'm using the correct syntax; so perhaps I'm misusing OCamllex(?) I admit, the scope the header, rules, and trailer are not clear to me. I've searched for solution in documentation, but tutorials targeted toward OCamllex are scarce. Can anyone tell deduce what I'm doing wrong? Does OCamllex allow the StringMap module to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that no `StringMap` module exists: you have to generate one with a functor application such as `module StringMap = Map.Make (String)`. Place this in the *header*, not the trailer. (The trailer code will be placed at the end of the generated file, and thus bindings established in it cannot be seen from within your lexer code.)

If you like you may also open the module:

```
open module StringMap = Map.Make (String)
```

Opening modules is considered somewhat poor style, though. In particular avoid opening modules such as applications of `Map` and `Set`, as their definitions of `compare` will shadow the usual one from `Pervasives` and generate confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's not clear to me how the header, rules, and trailer are scoped. Are the bindings I establish in header available in the trailer? If I planned on only using StringMap in the trailer, would it suffice to only open the module there? And if it's considered poor style to open modules, how else to I access StringMaps -- as it's not part of the standard library.

Comment: Yes, bindings you establish in the header are available in the trailer (and in the rules). If you only use something in the trailer, you only need to bind it there, but you need to bind it before use. For using names within a module without opening it, just prefix the name with the module: `StringMap.find` instead of just `find`. (You'll still need to *create* that module with `module StringMap = ...` first.)

Comment: Ahh, you're right -- I need to create the module itself. There's no opening a module that's not part of the standard library. Thank you for your patience; this is my second week using the language!